# Azure Portal - Dashboard Not Found (new Portal)

Tags: azure, azureportal

After sharing my Azure Portal Dashboard yesterday I think I accidentally deleted my default dashboard as it had the same name as the shared one. Now when I log into the Portal I'm getting the following message:

> *Dashboard not found We could not load the dashboard named 'private/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'. Refresh the portal to
>   try again.*

I have created a new dashboard and can select it from the drop down, but I was wondering if anyone knew a trick to make the new dashboard the default, and prevent this message from appearing.

Comment: Would like to downvote my own post!! I was using a bookmark that had the old dashboard in it.

Comment: This post is useful. I am a fan of keeping bookmarks and I was always wondering why the azure dashboard goes missing every time. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My issue was that I had bookmarked an old dashboard link. Double-check your bookmarks and make sure that you're using the correct version: https://portal.azure.com/

Answer (score 0):

The reason this was happening for me was permissions. Also make sure you assign the user/user group to the share access section of the dashboard as demonstrated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/azure-portal-dashboard-share-access)